# IPyton notebook: how do I change the text color in output cells?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using a `Jupyter` notebook and I've succesfully (that is, according to my taste) styled it using a `CSS` style file.

Now, I'd like to **globally** change the text color in all output cells.

Output, as far as I can see by inspecting a live notebook, is wrapped in `<pre>...</pre>` tags but adding the snippet

```
pre {color:red;}
```

to my style file didn't work as expected. It seems that `pre` doesn't support the `color` attribute, so sad...

To finish the list of my tentatives, I tried also with

```
.output_area {font-size:120%;color:red;}
```

That changed the font size as expected, but text is still very black.

How do I change the text color in output cells? thanks in advance,

Comment: Juust in case, I'll point out that you have an extra `'` in `pre {color:red'}`. That aside, try `pre {color:red !important;}`.

Comment: Apostrophe and semicolon are so close on a keyboard... that said, it works as expected and if you like to provide an answer I will be glad to accept and upvote it, for now thanks a lot!

Comment: Already had the answer ready, I just wanted to make sure it would work ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `!important` flag to the CSS rule:

```
pre {
    color:red !important;
}
```

`!important` tells the browser to prioritize this rule over any others, even if they would otherwise have a higher priority.